# Incorrect output while using dictionary tables inside Trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I am using `ALL_TABLES/ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` to get count of tables in my schema (`EDW_SRC`) and another schema(`EDW_STG`). I get correct counts when i run the query in my sql developer as shown below. But if i put the same query inside a trigger, i get wrong count for other schema(`EDW_STG`).

Please refer below code: 
(This is just a sample code to replicate the issue, not my business requirement. I am referring `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` in my actual code to get the number of columns in a particular table in different schema, for which i have Select access.)

```
select user from dual;

USER
-----
EDW_SRC

DROP TABLE ABC;
Table ABC dropped.

CREATE TABLE ABC(ID NUMBER);
Table ABC created.

select count(1) EDW_STG_CNT 
from all_tables
where owner='EDW_STG';--Different Schema

EDW_STG_CNT
----------
101

select count(1) EDW_SRC_CNT 
from all_tables
where owner='EDW_SRC';--My Schema

 EDW_SRC_CNT
------------
1554

create or replace trigger trig_test_dml_abc
before insert on abc
DECLARE
V_STG_CNT number :=NULL;
V_SRC_CNT number :=NULL;
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('***** TRIGGER OUTPUT *****');
select count(1) into V_SRC_CNT from all_tables
where owner='EDW_SRC'; --My Schema
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('My Schema EDW_SRC_CNT :'||V_SRC_CNT);

select count(1) into V_STG_CNT from all_tables
where owner='EDW_STG'; --Different Schema
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Different Schema EDW_STG_CNT :'||V_STG_CNT);
end;

Trigger TRIG_TEST_DML_ABC compiled

INSERT INTO ABC VALUES (2);
1 row inserted.

***** TRIGGER OUTPUT *****
My Schema EDW_SRC_CNT :1554
Different Schema EDW_STG_CNT :2
```

The Different Schema count should be 101. Why is it coming as 2.

Oracle Version:
    Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Thanks
K

Comment: Are you sure you are  running the `trigger` and query in the same database's connection?

Comment: Is your access to the objects in the `EDW_STG` schema granted via a role?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes I am running it in same db connection.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes , the access is granted via a role.

Comment: @Kapil - then [see this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/managing-security-for-definers-rights-and-invokers-rights.html#GUID-EF625176-A3AA-47F5-BAEE-248DBAAF22A3), which explains what's going on. Inside the trigger you are not seeing the tables where the access is coming from the role. Try running the standalone count after doing `set role none` and you'll see the same thing.